# Moving windows down through a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, moving-average

I'd like to take a vector of numerics, then using a specified window width & stride I want to run down through the vector capturing the means of each window by their stride. I can code this but I'm wondering if there's a neater way with a package etc..?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve what you need is by using `rollapply` from `zoo` package.

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(x, width = 7, by = 4, mean)
#[1] 622.1429 682.8571 540.7143
```

**DATA**

```
x <-c(267, 497, 836, 498, 923, 836, 498, 923, 267, 497, 836, 498, 923, 267, 497)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks....saves allot of manual coding.